# Загрузить данные в CKEditor

Tags: ajax, ckeditor

Пытаюсь настроить CKEditor. Сохраняю данные из него Ajax-ом в базу. В коде страницы есть классы и стили, для того чтобы не обрезались в настройках CKEditor, прописал `config.allowedContent = true`.

Теперь обратная ситуация: требуется данные получить из базы (также Ajax-ом) и загрузить в CKEditor. Делаю следующим образом:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['htmltxt'].setData($htmltxt);
```

Где `htmltxt` - это id поля textarea, к которому подключен CKEditor, а в переменной `$htmltxt` хранится код из базы.

Проблема заключается в том, что с помощью настройки `config.allowedContent = true` теги не обрезаются, когда получаешь данные, но эта настройка не спасает от того, чтобы теги не обрезались, когда передаешь данные.

Как правильно надо передавать данные в CKEditor или какую настройку необходимо установить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Для того, чтобы передать данные в это поле надо воспользоваться методом `insertHtml`, а для того, чтобы не резались тегом - указать опцию `unfiltered_html`:
`CKEDITOR.instances['htmltxt'].insertHtml($htmltxt, "unfiltered_html");`